# Python urllib add useragent header

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib

Currently I have the following code to check png images file size:

```
filesize = urllib.urlopen(url).info()['content-length']
```

How can I add a custom `useragent` to `urllib` request?

Answer (score 1):

From the Python [urllib documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request):

```
import urllib.request
opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
opener.open('http://www.example.com/')
```

Comment: The problem is that I am working with python 2.7 and `urllib.request` does not exist in python 2.7 version.

Comment: Ah okay, are you able to use urllib2? The same code would work if you just changed the import.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for urllib/urllib2 recommends using requests, which has a much easier to use API

```
import requests
size = requests.get(url, headers = {'User-agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}).headers['content-length']
```